# Chef on Vagrant Box: Can't find encrypted data bag secret

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

When provisioning a vagrant box with (hosted-)chef I get the following error:

```
No such file or directory - file not found '/tmp/encrypted_data_bag_secret'
```

Here is the call causing the error:

```
ssl = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("ssl", s[:id])
```

I also can't find the `encrypted_data_bag_secret` in `/etc/chef` where it normally resides on my other servers.

Am I missing a config which uploads the data bag secret?

Here's the rest of the stack trace:

```
[2013-02-14T16:51:15+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-02-14T16:51:15+00:00] FATAL: Saving node information to /srv/chef/file_store/failed-run-data.json
[2013-02-14T16:51:15+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-02-14T16:51:15+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /srv/chef/file_store/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-02-14T16:51:15+00:00] FATAL: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - file not found '/tmp/encrypted_data_bag_secret'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When provisioning a vagrant box, you have to provide a path to your data bags secret key, if you want to use encrypted data bags.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  [...]
  chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path = '/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret'
  [...]
end
```

Comment: Nice man! I found this piece of information nowhere. It's strange because in the knife.rb file the setting is called 'encrypted_data_bag_secret_key'. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that you have to provide a path on your local machine for chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path. It will then put the key to chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret, by default "/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag".

Comment: I added an update to Thomas' comment as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Quick amendment to Thomas Obermüller's response to Draco Ater's answer above. In Vagrant 1.5.1 through Vagrant 1.6.5 (and possibly earlier than 1.5.1; I didn't try it), there are a couple of changes:

1. `chef.encrypted_data_bag_secret` is deprecated, and setting it has no effect.
2. Vagrant puts the encrypted key at `/tmp/vagrant-chef-2/encrypted_data_bag_secret_key`, instead of defaulting to `/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret` as it did initially.

Comment: Is it always vagrant-chef-2?  On my first run, it put it at vagrant-chef-1.

Comment: You're probably using Vagrant 1 then?

Comment: Looks like I'm on `1.6.5`.  But it also tells me that the latest version is `1.7.1`.  Weird.