# vagrant 1.5.4 chef_solo encrypted data bag

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I am running `vagrant` 1.5.4. in any previous releases i could set the `chef_solo` provisioner configuration to reference the encrypted data bag key as [it appears here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880503/chef-on-vagrant-box-cant-find-encrypted-data-bag-secret), but now I receive the following message, see the snippet below:

```
$ vagrant --version
Vagrant 1.5.4

$ vagrant up
...
DEPRECATION: Chef encrypted_data_bag_secret has no effect anymore.
Remove this from your Vagrantfile since it'll be removed in the next
Vagrant version.
...
ERROR: Is a directory - /tmp/vagrant-chef-2/encrypted_data_bag_secret_key
FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Sometimes I receive the message

```
ERROR: No secret specified to load_secret and no secret found at /etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret
```

Any idea how this issue can be resolved, or shall I downgrade?

**UPDATE 1:**

[investigating the changes](http://gitelephant.cypresslab.net/vagrant/commit/8581a93e76cb08f9f8a6a306c40179e6e5dfbd29) (on a different provisioner) reveals that `encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path` still exist, and even though I set it to reference the correct path, I still get the deprecation message above. Besides I wonder which file is being resolved or used as the encrypted data bag file.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be fixed if the attribute is changed from `encrypted_data_bag_secret` to `encrypted_data_bag_secret_key_path`. the latter is kinda misleading, it does not refer to the path, rather, it refers to the key itself.