# Programatically determine the location of the vagrant-chef directory

Tags: configuration, vagrant, chef-infra

Our testing system requires the use of data bags.  The data bag secret key is generally located at

```
/tmp/vagrant-chef-1/encrypted_data_bag_secret_key
```

However, the folder sometimes is `vagrant-chef` or `vagrant-chef-2`.  Is there a way to determine this from within the Vagrantfile?

Comment: May be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880503/chef-on-vagrant-box-cant-find-encrypted-data-bag-secret ?